# How to get variables and .pb file from checkpoint in TensorFlow?

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning

I am looking to serve the Tensorflow models to make a Docker image and deploy using AWS. For this I need to have .pb and variables files that is must while serving any Tensorflow model. But, I only have checkpoint file of the model. Is there any way to restore variables folder from the checkpoint file?

I am able to create the .pb file, but not sure how to get the variables folder.

Answer (score 0):

```py
ckpt = tf.train.latest_checkpoint(args.model_path)
model.load_weights(ckpt)
ckpt_filename = os.path.basename(ckpt)
saved_model_path = os.path.join('pb_files', ckpt_filename)
model.save(saved_model_path)
```

https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/saved_model

Hello, I created this snippet from the above document. This code will create pb file, variables folder, and assets folder.